# Dask read_csv failing

Tags: dask

I have gone through the issues/fixes related to this on [github](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2357). I have 15K columns, so I am looking for a more concise solution.

This is the syntax I tried:

```
 minifile_df = dd.read_csv(minifile, dtype='category', \
            na_filter=False, engine='c')
```

This gives me:

> ValueError: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample` in the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`

If I include, `sample=1e9`, I get (despite the `dtype` keyword argument):

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I do not want to state the metadata (suggested as the best solution in the above link) in the program because of the large number of columns.

Is there any other way to define all the columns as category/string?

Comment: Is this issue resolved now? I am also facing the same issue. Please help if any solution works for you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, I stopped using Dask altogether because of the above and a couple of other issues. It comes with its own baggage and is yet to mature.

Comment: So, what are other alternatives you used for a large datasets. Pandas dataframe not working for large datasets.

Comment: Typical workarounds such dumping manageable chunks to disk, using baremetal Numpy arrays, manual parallelism, etc.